# Magento Connect Manager is throwing a "no releases, skipping" error

Tags: magento

I'm looking to install a Magento extension and whenever I enter the extension key it throws me the error:

```
community/gtspeed_by_gossamer_threads: No releases for 'gtspeed_by_gossamer_threads', skipping
```

A number of people have posted about this exact same issue and were able to fix it by switching their preferred state to match the extension's release. This isn't working for me. I've tried using Alpha, Beta and Stable and nothing works. I thought it may have something to do with this particular extension package but I tried installing few other extensions and it threw the same error, even when re-installing the Mage_Downloader package straight from the MCM interface. Uploading a package file didn't do it either.

Has anyone else come across this, or have any idea how to fix this? This is even more frustrating as I've installed extensions just fine before, and I imagine it is probably a relatively simple configuration change. I'm currently running Magento v. 1.7.0.2 and MCM v. 1.7.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered what was going wrong, or put more aptly, how I incorrectly configured the Connect Manager. I tried numerous permissions configurations of the downloader/ directory, installing via pear, manually unpacking the extension package (I'm still unclear as to why that didn't work). The problem lied with the Connect Channel Protocol - which was set to FTP instead of HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version you are trying to install because your are using latest version of Magento so to need to install version 2.0 if available for that module.

Happy to Help You :)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Arya. I've tried using both the Connect 1.0 and 2.0 key versions. The 2.0 key gives me the previously mentioned error and the 1.0 key gives me, "Cannot connect to host: magento-community."